# "Unmerging" merged google calendar data with jq

Tags: icalendar, jq

I have ical data containing a calendar owner's events (UID contains google.com) and events imported from hebcal.com (UID contains hebcal). I'd like to use jq to to make two separate and complete ical files. ical2json converts the .ics to .json . So far I have managed to isolate the data with

```
cat basic.json | jq '.VCALENDAR[].VEVENT[] | select(.UID | contains("google.com"))'
```

How do I recreate the original structure including just the google.com or hebal.com data?

Here's sample json of the whole structure with two events, one from google, one from hebcal. So imagine producing the same structure, but with just google events.

```
{
  "VCALENDAR": [
    {
      "PRODID": "-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN",
      "VERSION": "2.0",
      "CALSCALE": "GREGORIAN",
      "METHOD": "PUBLISH",
      "X-WR-CALNAME": "Events - TS Cinnaminson",
      "X-WR-TIMEZONE": "America/New_York",
      "VTIMEZONE": [
        {
          "TZID": "America/New_York",
          "X-LIC-LOCATION": "America/New_York",
          "DAYLIGHT": [
            {
              "TZOFFSETFROM": "-0500",
              "TZOFFSETTO": "-0400",
              "TZNAME": "EDT",
              "DTSTART": "19700308T020000",
              "RRULE": "FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU"
            }
          ],
          "STANDARD": [
            {
              "TZOFFSETFROM": "-0400",
              "TZOFFSETTO": "-0500",
              "TZNAME": "EST",
              "DTSTART": "19701101T020000",
              "RRULE": "FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "VEVENT": [
        {
          "DTSTART;VALUE=DATE": "20170930",
          "DTEND;VALUE=DATE": "20171001",
          "DTSTAMP": "20170626T155902Z",
          "UID": "hebcal-20170930-6d1036bc2e3a7c743225174c4feb5d1f",
          "URL": "http://hebcal.com/h/yom-kippur",
          "CLASS": "PUBLIC",
          "CREATED": "20170603T024831Z",
          "DESCRIPTION": "Day of Atonement\\n\\nhttp://hebcal.com/h/yom-kippur",
          "LAST-MODIFIED": "20170626T153742Z",
          "LOCATION": "",
          "SEQUENCE": "0",
          "STATUS": "CONFIRMED",
          "SUMMARY": "Yom Kippur",
          "TRANSP": "OPAQUE",
          "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS": "OOF"
        },
        {
          "DTSTART": "20170731T233000Z",
          "DTEND": "20170801T003000Z",
          "DTSTAMP": "20170626T155902Z",
          "UID": "va6vhj4qba2rll8epdmccnjs@google.com",
          "CREATED": "20170523T010707Z",
          "DESCRIPTION": "",
          "LAST-MODIFIED": "20170523T010707Z",
          "LOCATION": "",
          "SEQUENCE": "0",
          "STATUS": "CONFIRMED",
          "SUMMARY": "Service",
          "TRANSP": "OPAQUE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired output is:

```
{
  "VCALENDAR": [
    {
      "PRODID": "-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN",
      "VERSION": "2.0",
      "CALSCALE": "GREGORIAN",
      "METHOD": "PUBLISH",
      "X-WR-CALNAME": "Events - TS Cinnaminson",
      "X-WR-TIMEZONE": "America/New_York",
      "VTIMEZONE": [
        {
          "TZID": "America/New_York",
          "X-LIC-LOCATION": "America/New_York",
          "DAYLIGHT": [
            {
              "TZOFFSETFROM": "-0500",
              "TZOFFSETTO": "-0400",
              "TZNAME": "EDT",
              "DTSTART": "19700308T020000",
              "RRULE": "FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU"
            }
          ],
          "STANDARD": [
            {
              "TZOFFSETFROM": "-0400",
              "TZOFFSETTO": "-0500",
              "TZNAME": "EST",
              "DTSTART": "19701101T020000",
              "RRULE": "FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "VEVENT": [
        {
          "DTSTART": "20170731T233000Z",
          "DTEND": "20170801T003000Z",
          "DTSTAMP": "20170626T155902Z",
          "UID": "va6vhj4qba2rll8epdmccnjs@google.com",
          "CREATED": "20170523T010707Z",
          "DESCRIPTION": "",
          "LAST-MODIFIED": "20170523T010707Z",
          "LOCATION": "",
          "SEQUENCE": "0",
          "STATUS": "CONFIRMED",
          "SUMMARY": "Service",
          "TRANSP": "OPAQUE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]   
}
```

Comment: Show us your input json in question and _exact_ final output you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *update-assignment* operator `|=`:

```
jq '.VCALENDAR[0].VEVENT |= map(select(.UID | contains("google.com")))' base.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "VCALENDAR": [
    {
      "PRODID": "-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN",
      "VERSION": "2.0",
      "CALSCALE": "GREGORIAN",
      "METHOD": "PUBLISH",
      "X-WR-CALNAME": "Events - TS Cinnaminson",
      "X-WR-TIMEZONE": "America/New_York",
      "VTIMEZONE": [
        {
          "TZID": "America/New_York",
          "X-LIC-LOCATION": "America/New_York",
          "DAYLIGHT": [
            {
              "TZOFFSETFROM": "-0500",
              "TZOFFSETTO": "-0400",
              "TZNAME": "EDT",
              "DTSTART": "19700308T020000",
              "RRULE": "FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU"
            }
          ],
          "STANDARD": [
            {
              "TZOFFSETFROM": "-0400",
              "TZOFFSETTO": "-0500",
              "TZNAME": "EST",
              "DTSTART": "19701101T020000",
              "RRULE": "FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "VEVENT": [
        {
          "DTSTART": "20170731T233000Z",
          "DTEND": "20170801T003000Z",
          "DTSTAMP": "20170626T155902Z",
          "UID": "va6vhj4qba2rll8epdmccnjs@google.com",
          "CREATED": "20170523T010707Z",
          "DESCRIPTION": "",
          "LAST-MODIFIED": "20170523T010707Z",
          "LOCATION": "",
          "SEQUENCE": "0",
          "STATUS": "CONFIRMED",
          "SUMMARY": "Service",
          "TRANSP": "OPAQUE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```